# How do I query an image with a specific ID in Puppeteer?

Tags: puppeteer

I need a Page in Puppeteer to wait for a selector to appear - specifically an image with an ID attribute.

I am trying to wait for it to appear so that I can run a Jest assertion on it, and the tag only appears after a response is returned from pressing a button.

I've tried something like this:

```
    await page.waitForSelector('img#testVideoText');
```

But that doesn't seem to work. How can I query a tag with an ID attribute?

Answer (score 1):

Add some timeout or just add `0` as it disabling the timeout and waitForSelector function will runs forever.

```
await page.waitForSelector('img#testVideoText', {timeout : 0});
```

Answer (score 0):

what do you mean by `But that doesn't seem to work` ... do you get an error or it just doesn't wait for element ? you need to be more specific and add your errors

sometimes element exists on the page  , but its not visible 
try this

```
await page.waitForSelector('img#testVideoText', {visible: true});
```